# Cassandra Replication not working accross data centers

Tags: cassandra, replication

I am new to Cassandra and have configured cassandra cluster as multiple aws data center.
I have 3 replicat in eu-central-1 and 3 replicat in eu-west-1.
I have created keyspace from eu-central-1 seed as following: CREATE KEYSPACE my_test WITH REPLICATION = {'class':'NetworkTopologyStrategy', 'eu-west-1':'3', 'eu-central-1':'3'}; after that I have created several tables under this keyspace.
Those keyspace and tables didn't replicated to the eu-west-1 3 replicat, should those keyspace and the tables be replicated to eu-west-1 seeds automatically ? if yes , what's wrong with my configurations.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, whatever tables belong in the keyspace `my_test` should have replicated to both DCs.

How are you determining that the tables have not replicated? I'd be happy to update my answer when you update your original question.

Since you're new to Cassandra, I recommend [datastax.com/dev](https://www.datastax.com/dev) which has links to free hands-on tutorials where you can quickly learn the basics of Cassandra.

This tutorial is a good place to start -- [datastax.com/try-it-out](https://www.datastax.com/try-it-out).

We also have FREE live workshops where you get to learn hands-on in a fun environment with other participants and have a chance to win prizes. Have a look at the list of upcoming workshops here -- [datastax.com/workshops](https://www.datastax.com/workshops). Cheers!

Comment: Hi Erick,
the issue is this region > eu-west-1 instances are not including within the cluster. the eu-central-1 instances replicated normally. How can I know that, simply after I have created the keyspace, I have found it in the central-1 instances normally but nothing changed in  eu-west-1 instances .

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean. It would be better if you could update your original question with examples. In any case, check for schema disagreement. But without examples, I'm having a hard time deciphering what you mean.